# How to use C# to convert any file to some other arbitrary format(.rjb) & recover to original format?

Tags: c#, file, format

This is my first question in Stackoverflow

I am trying to convert some files(.txt,.mp3,.mp4,.pdf,.png,.exe etc.) in a folder to a format .rjb, created by me. And I also want to recover the original files from the .rjb files. But every files other than .txt files get corrupted. Please help me, to accomplish this. The below code is what I am using.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace rjbformat
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            try
            {


                //string data = Convert.ToString(File.ReadAllBytes(textBox1.Text));
               // string datas = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);
                //string dat = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text, Encoding.ASCII);
                //var dataS = Convert.ToString(datas);



                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(textBox1.Text + ".rjb"))
                {
                    sw.Write(textBox3.Text);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Specified Input file DOESNOT EXIST!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                //throw;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select Input file");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Text File (Rajib)";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files(*.txt;*.cod;*.ubc)|*.txt;*.cod;*.ubc";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            textBox2.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName + ".rjb";
            File.Copy(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text,true);
FileAccess.ReadWrite.ToString(textBox1.Text);


            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
        /*    foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                textBox3.Text += line+"\r\n";
            }*/

            File.AppendAllLines(textBox2.Text, lines);


     //       FileStream fs = new FileStream(textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open);
      //      int hexIn;
      //      String hex = "";

    //        for (int i = 0; i<50/*(hexIn = fs.ReadByte()) != -1*/; i++)
      //      {
        //        hex = string.Format("{0:X2}", fs.ReadByte());
          //     // int bina = fs.ReadByte();
            //    textBox3.Text += hex;
            //}


        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You need to explain how you convert to this new format. And what is this format. From your question it seems a bit odd and unnessessary.

Comment: Looks like you're reading binary files with text file tools

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is storing one or more files into your `.rjb` format and want to get them back intact, this sounds a lot like creating archive files. In that case, you may want to consider just using a standard zip file and customize the extension.

Here's an example using the [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace CustomZip
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
            string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.rjb";
            string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to add a reference to System.IO.Compression.FileSystem to your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot digitalnoiz, you are correct I want something like .zip but not exactly that because, zip canbe extracted by any one & data will not remain private(protected) anymore, if not password protected! & It is also not convenient to remember too many password for lots of files. So, I want such a file format(.rjb) that will be opened by a specialy designed program in the original format the files were.    So, please guide me how it can be accomplished. Thank you once again. :)